# Coldfusion - Twitter style mentions to link records

Tags: regex, coldfusion

was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction on this one.

The system I'm building allows users to add comments to records. If the user wants to reference another record in their comment I want them to be able to use the @ symbol followed by the 5 digit record id.

For example when a user submits a comment like "*Updated details for this record and record @25645*" I need it to be outputted with a href around the "@25645" which will link to the record in question.

I'm trying to use REReplaceNoCase with limited success.

```
<cfset LinkableComments = REReplaceNoCase(Comments, "@[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]", "<a href=""detailPage.cfm?ID=Test"">Test</a>", "all") />
```

I can't figure out how to get the records id back into the URL's.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried setting it manually? `<cfset URL.record = LinkableComments />`? (Where [record] is your URL param)

Comment: Regex's are not my strong suit, but I think what you need is a [back reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7e91.html).

Comment: @Leigh they are rather tricky in CF, aren't they? No lookbehind assertion threw me off for a while.

Comment: @RUJordan - Yes, there are few things like that I never seem to remember until *after* struggling with an expression for while. Trying to figure out why it does not work as expected ;-)

Comment: Lookbehind assertions and back references are two entirely different things. The first is not available in CF (but lookahead is) and is an assertion (verify that X exists before the position), the latter is a reference to a captured group.

Comment: @PeterBoughton I know that, I was saying how CF regex can be tricky

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misread what you/Leigh were saying. ( It's really not tricky though. ;) )

Comment: Knew I should not have edited my comment trailer: "... for me anyway. Though not to people like Peter" ;-)

Comment: It's _really_ not difficult once you understand the key concepts - it's just there's no good explanations/tutorials which start at the conceptual level, they all jump around in the syntax and get people confused unnecessarily (or start with the compsci regular expression stuff which is just too boring).

Comment: Exactly. I know it is not rocket science, but ... regex's are not intuitive to most ;-) Connecting the dots between high level concept and practical examples is where most sites fall down. Unfortunately, that is typical of a lot of documentation. The good ones use a building block approach, with one lesson building on the next. Combined with common (real world) examples, rather than going from zero to sixty mph in one lesson.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leigh is correct, you can use a back reference like so:

`<cfset LinkableComments = REReplaceNoCase(Comments, "@([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])", "<a href=""detailPage.cfm?ID=\1"">@\1</a>", "all") />`

Basically you place the regex "group" you wish to capture and replace inside `(` and `)`, then refer to that in the replace with argument as `\1` ( because this was the first group, \2 for second, etc... )

Try it yourself [here](http://www.trycf.com/scratch-pad/gist/8849236) ( <-- ***Edit:** Gist was updated to show the `@([0-9]{5})` syntax suggested by @PeterBoughton*)

Comment: There is always `\0` which refers to the entire match. So _if_ keeping the `@` is desired use `\0` instead of `@\1` - but I strongly recommend _not_ littering output text with unnecessary symbols.

Comment: Well there you go, never knew that! Thanks for sharing that @PeterBoughton

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation on [REReplace](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=regexp_10.html), you ought to be able to use the following:

```
REReplaceNoCase(Comments, "@([0-9]{5})", "<a href=""detailPage.cfm?ID=\1"">Test</a>", "all")
```

I'll test when my CF server is back up again

Comment: Or just write `@([0-9]{5})`

Comment: Thanks Barnyr & Peter this worked perfectly! Was thinking there had to be a nicer way to write "@([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])"